# NTPD deleting interface eno3

Tags: ntp, deleting

Our server is loosing connection one time every day and we must reboot it manualy to get the netword coming back! The only line we can see and is certainly responsible of that is this one :

```
ntpd[1009]: Deleting interface #3 eno3, 137.84.xxx.xxx#123, interface stats: received=1274, sent=1276, dropped=0, active_time=86401 secs
```

We are running a brand new server with Debian 10 installed.
Anyone can help on this problem? I saw a lot of threads on this error but each time the config file is /etc/sysconfig/xxxxx but on our server there is no such directory, it seems to be /etc/network and there is not eth0 files to setup like we can read...
Other solution I found is options -L on ntpd configuration, but same poroblem here, the configuration file for NTP is not the one we can read... :-(

Thanks

Comment: You are probably looking for the error in the wrong place. When `ntpd` says "Deleting interface", it means that `ntpd` is about to stop listening on that interface. Most probably the interface disappeared, got deconfigured, or the connection was broken, and `ntpd` is acting on this change, not causing it.

Comment: Ok, thanks... I'll check elsewhere.